# ‘Memory-Game' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you please review my code for reusability, clarity, readability and any bad stuff or bad practices?
Brief Description:-
Its a card memory-game, when you click two cards, it sees if they are same symbols and if yes, it matches them and keeps them open, if cards does not match it closes them and player tries to match cards in as min moves n time as possible as it keeps track of time and clicks. When all cards are matched a congratulating message pops-up and shows times n moves and also asks player if they want to play again, if player press button yes, game shuffles all cards. You can play and see complete code in below link.
Thanks.

Full code [here](https://codepen.io/ma-halepoto/pen/LJPpKz).

```js
// Shuffle function 
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}


window.onload = function () {
    let openedCards  =  [];
        matchedCards =  [];
        currentCard  =  [];
        previouseCard= 0;
        moveCount = 0;
        restart = document.getElementsByClassName ('restart');
        modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

        // console.log (restart); just to see if restart works
        restart[0].addEventListener ('click', function (){
            location.reload();

        })
    // console.log("It's loaded!") to check if this works
    const cards = ['fa-diamond','fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o','fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-cube', 'fa-cube', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle',
     'fa-bomb','fa-bomb' ]; 
    let shuffleCards = shuffle (cards);
    // console.log (shuffleCards); to check if this works
    let cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName('symbols');
    // console.log (cardElements); to check if this works
    for (i=0; i < cardElements.length; i++ ) {
        cardElements[i].className = shuffleCards[i]+ ' fa symbols';

    }

    // initialising popup 

    function popup() {
                    modal.style.display = "flex";
                    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'You did it in '+ moveCount+ ' moves'  + ' and ' + seconds+ ' seconds.';
    }

    // Closing popup by clicking x
    span.onclick = function closeX () {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }

    // function close popup by clicking any where
    window.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (event.target == modal) {
                            modal.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }

    // Stopwatch initialisation
    let stopWatch = document.getElementById ('timer');
        time = 0;
        seconds=0

    // start time
    function startTime () {
        time = setInterval ( function (){
            seconds++;
            stopWatch.innerHTML = seconds + ' s';
        }, 1000); 
    }

    // stop the time function
    function stopTime ()    {
        clearInterval (time);
    }

    let displayCards = document.getElementsByClassName ('card');       
        console.log (displayCards);
    let clickFlag = true;

    // Click Event
    function cardClick () {
        if (!clickFlag) {
            //alert ('Please wait you are clicking too fast');
            return;
        }
        currentCard = this;
        currentCard.removeEventListener ('click', cardClick); 
        console.log (currentCard);



        // updating move counts
        let countMoves = document.getElementById ('moves');

        moveCount++ ;
        countMoves.innerHTML= moveCount;
        console.log(countMoves);

        // star ranking;
        if ( moveCount === 20) {
            let removeStar = document.getElementById('star3');
            removeStar.style.display = 'none';
        } else if (moveCount ===30) {
            let removeStarTwo = document.getElementById ('star2');
            removeStarTwo.style.display = 'none';
            }   

        // start  stopwatch at the first click.
        if ( moveCount ===1) {
            startTime ();
        }

            currentCard.classList.add('open', 'show');


            if (previouseCard) {

                clickFlag = false;
                // matching cards
                if (currentCard.innerHTML === previouseCard.innerHTML) {
                    currentCard.classList.add('match');
                    previouseCard.classList.add('match');
                    matchedCards.push(currentCard,previouseCard);

                    // console.log ('match'); this line here for just test purpose
                    previouseCard = null ;

                    // check if won
                    if (cards.length === matchedCards.length) {

                        // stopping stopwatch 
                        stopTime();

                        // calling popup function 
                        popup ();

                    }
                    clickFlag = true;
                } else {
                    // when cards are not matched
                    setTimeout (function(){

                        currentCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show');  
                        previouseCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show');
                        currentCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
                        previouseCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
                        previouseCard = null ;
                        clickFlag = true;

                    }, 500);

                }


            } else {
                    previouseCard = currentCard ;   
                    openedCards.push(this); 
                    clickFlag = true;
                }                   
    } 

        // event listener function 
    for (i=0; i < displayCards.length; i++) {
        displayCards[i].addEventListener('click', cardClick);

    }

 }
```

Comment: He added a formatting element so that the formatting engine knows that the code is JavaScript and not HTML or CSS.  --> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/201984/revisions use the `side-by-side markdown` view option